# KDB/q How to left join on two columns

Tags: join, left-join, kdb

I am trying to left join one table to another. I have one table that looks like this:

WORKING_TABLE:

| Store | ID | Cost | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AXA | 2B | 2.3 | 2023.01.01 |
| DEP | 2B | 2.8 | 2023.01.01 |
| ZOO | 2B | 5.0 | 2023.01.02 |
| REP | 3C | 8.7 | 2023.04.04 |

And another called INFO_TABLE that looks like this:

| ID | Tax | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2B | 0.5 | 2023.01.01 |
| 2B | 0.9 | 2023.01.02 |
| 3C | 1.0 | 2023.04.04 |

As you can see, WORKING_TABLE has a lot more rows, and I'm trying to use left join using kdb on two columns (ID and Date) so that I can add the Tax column to the end of WORKING_TABLE, like this:

| Store | ID | Cost | Date | Tax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AXA | 2B | 2.3 | 2023.01.01 | 0.5 |
| DEP | 2B | 2.8 | 2023.01.01 | 0.5 |
| ZOO | 2B | 5.0 | 2023.01.02 | 0.9 |
| REP | 3C | 8.7 | 2023.04.04 | 1.0 |

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If any of the answers below have provided a solution for your question then please consider marking one as accepted. This helps future viewers of the question know if there is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you key the right table on the columns you want to join it should work so something like

```
working_table lj `id`date xkey info_table
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How would I only add the Tax column to the table using this left join?

Comment: `@mmv456` Not sure i fully understand the question, but if you are saying you're table has other columns that you don't want to join then you could do.   
```
    working_table lj select id,date,tax from `id`date xkey info_table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'lj' left join by making Date and ID as key columns for INFO_TABLE.

```
q) WORKING_TABLE lj `Date`ID xkey select Date,ID,Tax from INFO_TABLE

Read about lj here - https://code.kx.com/q/ref/lj/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That does correctly left join, how would I then only add the Tax column?

Comment: updated my answer to only add tax column in join